# Reading comma separated values

Tags: python

My file has 5 values separated by 1 comma and 1 space. Which are: **1, 2, 3, 5, 6**

However, no matter what I try (strip, split, etc) I just cant process the file and sum it to an accumulator (suma = 0).

When I try to convert the values to intergers I get the following error: *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3,5,6'*

How exactly can I read them, convert them and then sum them?

```
def main():

input_file = open('sumadatos.txt', 'r')
line = input_file.readline()
while line != '':
    value = int(line)
    suma += value 
print suma

main()
```

Comment: You want to print `17` as answer?

Comment: Well yeah, what I want to know is how can I read these values without getting an error when I try to convert them to intergers

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be

```
with open('sumadatos.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(sum(map(int, next(f).split(','))))
```

`int` can consume leading and trailing whitespace, so `int('  1  ')` => `1`

Comment: You could also do `f.read()` instead of `next(f)`, to ensure the entire contents of the file is read and not just the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead do, using the `ast` library

```
>>> f = open("sumadatos.txt")
>>> sum(ast.literal_eval(f.readline()))
17
```

But if you want to do it conventionally you can do

```
>>> sum(int(i) for i in f.readline().split(','))
17
```

Comment: indeed, so evil to use tuple eval

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is `literal_eval` ... Yay

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy` library has some great built in functions for parsing in delimited files into arrays.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
data = genfromtxt('sumadatos.txt', delimiter=',')
print data.sum()
```